# Pygame How to get the left,top,width, and height of an image

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement collisions into my game but I do not know how to get the rect attributes for my images. The player gets to choose where the images spawn(he places them) so I cannot set an exact number etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pygame.Surface` object has a method `get_rect` which returns an instance of a `pygame.Rect` that encloses the `Surface`.  Note that the position (`x` and `y` attributes of the `Rect`) starts at (0,0), but you can change this value and reference it whenever you blit to another surface.

So if you have a `pygame.Surface` named `surf`, and a screen surface called `screen`, you could do something like this:

```
surf_rect = surf.get_rect()
# move the surface 20 units to the right, and 15 units down
surf_rect.x += 20
surf_rect.y += 15
# now draw this surface to the screen based on the surf_rect's position
screen.blit(surf, (surf_rect.x, surf_rect.y))
```

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect

Additionally, `pygame.Surface` also has `get_width` and `get_height` methods that are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: this should be `screen.blit(surf,(surf_rect.x, surf_rect.y))`

Comment: Yep, thanks for catching it.